# HttpHostConnectException occured while executing multiple test in junit using Selenium2 WebDriver

Tags: exception, selenium, connection, webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.0 with the WebDriver. I am not using the TestCaseBase, etc. I am using only the webdriver.

I am also using JUnit with the Parameterized test. 
When running tests with the IEDriver - the first test runs fine, the second test gets a org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException.

Does anyone have experience with this? 
Does this seem like a bug or bad code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()`

See this: http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/6ade9e6ae1861a2/e1fd6423589b5d1d?lnk=gst&q=internetexplorerdriver+connection++refuse#e1fd6423589b5d1d